# On IOS when the app is closed, when clicking on a received notification it won't go through the sfmc_handle method and it always open the app instead

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

We tried to implement the sfmc_notification system in our flutter app, we setup sfmc and set **URLHandlingDelegate**, we are receiving the notifications which contains a url to open (deep linking), but when the app is closed it always open the application and nothing more. I realized that the **sfmc_handle** function is never hit in this case.
But when the app is already running or in the background it works ok and it would hit **sfmc_handle**.
Is there anything that we are missing ?

Comment: You have not implemented your App Delegate, or you have implemented it incorrectly. Refer to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I have tested [official SFMC learning app](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS) and looks like sfmc_handleURL callback won't be called when iOS app **is not running** (**killed**) and user taps on push notifications (It only opens the app) but it is working when app is running.

```swift
func sfmc_handleURL(_ url: URL, type: String) {
            // Very simply, send the URL returned from the MobilePush SDK to UIApplication to handle correctly.
            UIApplication.shared.open(url,
                                      options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                                        (success) in
                                        print("Open \(url): \(success)")
                                      })
        }
```

Flutter sfmc_plugin package:
https://pub.dev/packages/sfmc_plugin

Reported issue:
https://github.com/sefidgaran/salesforce-marketing-cloud/issues/2